# neo4j server on vpn can not be accesed from remote device

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

I am trying to host neo4j server on Ubuntu virtual private server version 16.04 LTS. On the server I have successfully installed neo4j server version: 3.3.1.

When I call nmap on the server I see that all relevant ports are open:

- 7473/tcp open unknown
- 7474/tcp open unknown
- 7687/tcp open unknown

When I run the nmap from my machine and target vps static IP address I see that this port are closed. I had this problem when I was configuring redis so I tried the same approach. There, the fix was in redis config file, so i looked for the same fix just for neo4j. Nothing worked but at this point after trying few solutions my neo4j config file had this changes:

```
# The network interface IP the shell will listen on (use 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
dbms.shell.host=0.0.0.0
# The port the shell will listen on, default is 1337.
dbms.shell.port=1337

 # The network interface IP the shell will listen on (use 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
dbms.shell.host=0.0.0.0
# The port the shell will listen on, default is 1337.
dbms.shell.port=1337

# HTTP Connector. There must be exactly one HTTP connector.
    dbms.connector.http.enabled=true
    dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:7474
    dbms.connector.http.address=0.0.0.0:7474

    # HTTPS Connector. There can be zero or one HTTPS connectors.
    dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
    dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:7473

    # The network interface IP the shell will listen on (use 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
    dbms.shell.host=0.0.0.0
    # The port the shell will listen on, default is 1337.
    dbms.shell.port=1337
```

I am new to neo4j so it is possible that i have create a trivial mistake or the change needed is trivial. If someone had experience with this please assist.

Comment: maybe not a neo4j issue, any firewall on your server ?

Comment: also, do not allow neoshell logins from other machines. 
SSH to your server then open neoshell from there